# Capitalize words in Python with exceptions (not every word)

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a table containing car brands, all in uppercase:

```
MERCEDES-BENZ, BMW, VW
```

I would like to have them written in a normal way:

```
Mercedes-Benz, BMW, VW
```

I already tried *"df.str.title()"* and it works fine.
The only problem is that it also turns "BMW" into "Bmw" and "VW" into "Vw".

I tried to apply an If-statement but haven't been successfull.

```
df['MakeText']=df['MakeText'].str.title()

if (df['MakeText'] == "BMW"):
df['MakeText']=df['MakeText'].str.uppercase()
elif df.MakeText=='Vw':
   df['MakeText']=df['MakeText'].str.uppercase()
```

**ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Comment: What methods are there in `dir(df['MakeText'].str)`?

Comment: methods? I am affraid I don't quite understand.

Comment: A method is a function that is bound to an object/class. For example, `upper` is a method of the `str` type. `dir(...)` gives you the attributes of the object, some of which may be methods (functions). See if there are any methods named what you need.